# Require.js optimize error

Tags: node.js, requirejs

When executing the optimize statement:

```
r.js -o app.build.js
```

Optimize command throws an error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '[...]/js/customizer-build/marionette.js'
```

**app.build.js**

```
({
    appDir: "./",
    baseUrl: "./",
    dir: "../customizer-build",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

Marionette is specified as a module in my require.config of **main.js**:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
    //....
        marionette: {
            deps: [
                'backbone'
            ],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        },
    //....

    paths: {
    //....
        marionette: '/js/lib/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.min',
    //....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a [`mainConfigFile` option](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27) set to point to `main.js` in your `app.build.js` file. Without it, the optimizer ignores the configuration in `main.js`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped clear the error for Marionette, but other libs are choking now - Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory /js/lib/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js // I'm starting to wonder if it was right to build the app with paths as absolute from htdoc root?

Comment: With what is present in the question at the moment, it is hard to tell what other things may be wrong. Absolute paths can make things difficult. I prefer not to use them if I can.